# Hangouts full screen chat window

Tags: google-chrome, google-hangouts

Is there a way I could use hangouts.google.com chat windows in a fullscreen mode? 
I mean, I use Messenger via messenger.com (full size) or Slack using the website slack.com (also full screen). 
When I open a Hangouts chat window, it is a very small window in the bottom right corner. I could open it up to a new window, but I would like to keep it inside the tab, not a new window.

Is there a way?

(I have a big screen, so it is kinda funny looking at the small thing in the corner)

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it is not currently possible to have Hangouts be fullscreen without opening a separate window for it. I believe this is because Google wants it to be perceived as an app, not just a website.

The closest you can get is making the whole thing fullscreen by simply clicking the maximize button while on the [Hangouts website](https://hangouts.google.com/) or using the [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog). You can also make individual conversations fullscreen by clicking the pop-out arrow in the top right of the conversation then clicking the maximize button for that conversation. This is true on the site, in the extension, and in Gmail.